# distinct values from 2 tables

Tags: hadoop, hive

assume I have 2 tables as below.

```
ID, NAME, NO
1, PK,101
2,AK,102
3,OK,103

ID,CITY,COUNTRY
1,NY,US
2,NJ,US
```

I need to get output as this, only the ID value

```
3
```

any help here.?

Answer (score 1):

select a.ID from table1 a left outer join table2 b on b.ID=a.ID where b.ID is null;

Comment: This won't work in cases where distinct value comes from table2 and not from table1

Comment: are you saying that you want ID of table1 that are not present in table2 and also ID of table2 that are not present in table1?

Comment: i need ID of table1 that are not present in table2

Answer (score 0):

You can basically do a **FULL JOIN** on both the tables and filter rows where ID is NULL for any of the tables. Assuming you have two tables named temp_table1 and temp_table2, following query should work:

> select * from (select (CASE WHEN temp_table1.id is NULL THEN temp_table2.id WHEN temp_table2.id is NULL THEN temp_table1.id ELSE NULL END) as id from temp_table1 FULL JOIN temp_table2 on temp_table1.id = temp_table2.id)q1 where id is not null;

Explanation:
First I am doing a full join on both the tables to get all the rows corresponding to both the tables.

Then in case condition I am checking that if id is NULL in table 1  then we will return the id from table 2.

Similarly if id is NULL in table2 we will return the id from table1. 
And if it is not NULL in any of the tables then we will return NULL.

Finally we are putting this in a sub query and returning rows where returned id is not null. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As @DRAGO replied, an OUTER JOIN should be sufficient & efficient in this case !